# C++ Standard Library Exception List?

Tags: c++, exception, stl

Is there a reference about C++ Standard Library Exceptions? I just want to know that which functions may throw an exception or not.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938979/what-exception-classes-are-in-the-standard-c-library

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, most of the standard library function don't throw exceptions themselves. They just pass on exception thrown by user code invoked by them. For example, if you `push_back()` an element to a vector, this can throw (due to memory allocation errors and) if the object's copy constructor throws.

A few notable exceptions (no pun intended) where library functions throw are:

- Some methods will throw `out_of_range` if the index provided is invalid:

  - `std::vector<>::at()`
  - `std::basic_string<>::at()`
  - `std::bitset<>::set()`, `reset()` and `flip()`.
- Some methods will throw `std::overflow_error` on integer overflow:

  - `std::bitset<>::to_ulong()` and (C++0x) `to_ullong()`.
- `std::allocator<T>` will pass on `std::bad_alloc` thrown by `new` which it invokes.
- Streams can be setup so that `std::ios_base::failure` are thrown when a state bit is set.
- Large array allocations can throw `std::bad_array_new_length`
- dynamic_cast on a reference can throw a `std::bad_cast` (technically not part of the standard library)
- Throwing an invalid exception from a function with an exception specification will throw a `std::bad_exception`
- Calling a `std::function::operator(...)` if it has no value will throw `std::bad_function_call`.
- Using `typeinfo` of a null pointer may throw a `std::bad_typeid`.
- Accessing a `weak_ptr` after the pointee has been released will throw a `std::bad_weak_ptr`.
- Incorrect usage of `std::promise/std::future` may throw a `std::future_error`.
- *(c++11)* The string conversion functions `std::stoi`, `std::stol`, `std::stoll`, `std::stoul`, `std::stoull`, `std::stof`, `std::stod`, and `std::stold` can throw both `std::invalid_argument` and `std::out_of_range`.
- *(c++11)* In the regex family, constructors and assign methods can throw `std::regex_error`.

(I'm making this a CW answer, so if anyone can think of more such, please feel free to append them here.)

Also, for the 3rd edition of *The C++ Programming Language*, Bjarne Stroustrup has a downloadable [appendix about exception safety](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_safe.pdf), which might be relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, what's the CW answer?

Comment: @Brian: It's "community wiki". Others are free to edit any CW answer (even when they don't have the rep to edit answers normally).

Answer (score 1):

The only functions guaranteed (by the compiler) to not throw are functions that have the `throw()` exception specification, like this:

```
void ThisFunctionNeverThrows() throw()
{
}
```

Otherwise, any other function can potentially throw an exception, unless they are specifically documented otherwise. You must consider exception safety when writing code in the face of exceptions.

See Bjarne Stroustup's article on exception safety and the standard library: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd_safe.pdf Starting on page 19 in the PDF you can find information on guarantees made by the standard containers.

Comment: This is not correct as many containers e.g. guarantee not to throw in `erase()`, yet this function is not `throw()`.  From language point of view what you wrote does make sense, but there are guarantees other than those specifically enforced by compiler.

Comment: @doublep: `erase()` *will* throw if the copy constructor of the element type throws.

Comment: From page 21 in the PDF I mentioned (Guarantees for `vector` and `deque`): "Unless thrown by the copy constructor or the assignment operator of the element type, no `erase()` throws an exception."

Comment: @Kenny: Not all containers copy anything in `erase()`.  Of course it can throw in a `vector`, but not in e.g. `list`.